# MongoDB keeps crashing--is it running out of memory or CPU?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have an issue where MongoDB keeps crashing on me:

`$ sudo cat /var/log/syslog` ->

```
Nov 28 14:06:58 ns557017 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Nov 28 14:06:58 ns557017 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 28 14:06:58 ns557017 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Nov 28 14:06:59 ns557017 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 28 14:06:59 ns557017 systemd[1]: Stopped MongoDB Database Server.
```

I am using Mongo's free monitoring, and it points me towards the CPU being overused:
[image]

However if I look at htop, the CPU always seems fine:
[image]

How can I deduce what is causing Mongo to crash on me? Thanks

Comment: From my experience, it caused by huge query/long process. Comment all places in the API where you call the database, and one by one uncomment them, to see that is the problematic action.

Comment: If you have access look up in the internal log `db.adminCommand({getLog:"global"})` for more details. I don't know if the system logs are that detailed. I'd also remove `htop` tag as it's not part of the problem.

Comment: Programs cannot run out of CPU hence that is not a valid crash reason. Read the server log (mongodb log not system log) for clues.